# How to simplify this array method?

Tags: java, arrays

Here is my code to an array method:

```
private int _a;

public static void main(String[] args) {}

public int[] countAll(String s) {
    int[] xArray = new int[27];
    int[] yArray = new int[27];
    _a = (int)'a';

    for (int i = 0; i < xArray.length; i++) {
        xArray[i] = _a;
        _a = _a++;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++) {
        s = s.toLowerCase();
        char c = s.charAt(j);
        int g = (int) c;
        int letterindex = g - yArray[0];
        if (letterindex >= 0 && letterindex <= 25) {
            xArray[letterindex]++;
        } else if (letterindex < 0 || letterindex > 25) {
            xArray[26]++;
        }
    }
    return xArray;
}
```

This code works in java but I was told that there is a simpler way. I am having a lot of trouble figuring out a simplified version of my code. Please help me.

Comment: Would help if you told us what it does..

Comment: For one thing `_a = _a++;` is the same as `_a++;`

Comment: for another thing, do you need this to be called each time within the for loop: "s = s.toLowerCase();"

Comment: what exactly is this suppose to do?  somethings do not make too much sense...for instance this line: "int letterindex = g - yArray[0];".   yArray is never changed after initialization and you are only ever accessing the first item.   why?

Comment: It is supposed to count the number of uppercase or lower case letters in a string. For example, a or A is supposed to be in position 0 of the array, b or B is supposed to be in position 1 of the array,and so on. Also the count of all characters must be within position 26.

Comment: @KarthikT.. No, they are not the same. After `_a = _a++` the value of `_a` will not change, whereas it will change on `_a++`. But I suspect, OP need the 2nd one. `_a = _a++` is doing something, he didn't probably noticed.

Comment: I think your first for-loop is completely unnecessary (and doesn't fit in what you want the function to do, and doesn't do what you think it does). Also, I think you want to replace `g - yArray[0]` with `g - 'a'` (and then yArray isn't used, so you can get rid it).

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is count the upper and lower case, that's a very roundabout way of doing it, what's wrong with something like:

```
public static int countUpper(String str)
{
    int upper = 0;
    for(char c : str.toCharArray())
    {
        if(Character.isUpperCase(c))
        {
            upper++;
        }
    }
    return upper;
}
```

Then just the same thing with `Character.isLowerCase(c)` for the opposite.

Comment: Why bother with the `Character.isLetter` check?  It's just redundant.

Comment: I think OP wants counts for each letter, not just a single count.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int[] countAll(String s) {
    int[] xArray = new int[27];

    for (char c : s.toLowerCase().toCharArray()){
        if (Character.isLetter(c))
            xArray[c -'a']++;
        else
            xArray[26]++;
    }

    return xArray;
}
```

Comment: You'll get an array index out of bounds. All out-of-bounds characters must be placed in index 26 (from what I can tell). Pretty sure the cast to `int` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two important improvements that should be made to your code:

- Add a method javadoc for `countAll`, so that readers don't have to trawl through 20+ lines of turgid code to reverse engineer what the method is *supposed to be*.
- Get rid of the `_a` abomination.  According to the most widely accepted Java coding standard, the underscore character has no place in a variable name.  Besides, `a` is about the most useless field name I've ever come across.  If it is intended to convey some meaning to the reader ... you have totally lost me.

  (Oh I get it.  It shouldn't be a field at all.  Bzzzt!!!)

---

Then there is the `yArray` array.  As far as I can tell the only place it is used is here:

```
int letterindex = g - yArray[0];
```

which is actually the same as:

```
int letterindex = g;
```

since `yArray[0]` is never assigned to.  In short `yArray` is completely redundant.

---

And this:

```
    if (letterindex >= 0 && letterindex <= 25) {
        xArray[letterindex]++;
    } else if (letterindex < 0 || letterindex > 25) {
        xArray[26]++;
    }
```

The condition in the `else` part is redundant.  Your code will be easier to read if you just write this:

```
    if (letterindex >= 0 && letterindex <= 25) {
        xArray[letterindex]++;
    } else {
        xArray[26]++;
    }
```

The two are equivalent.  Do you see why?

---

Finally the initialization of the `xArray` elements looks plain wrong to me.  If `xArray` contains counts, the elements need to start at zero.  (Didn't you wonder why your code was telling you that *every* string contained lots of "zees"?)

> *"This code works in java ..."*

I don't think so.  Maybe it compiles.  Maybe it runs without crashing.  But it *doesn't* give correct answers!

Comment: @StephenC.. You also might point out the side effects of re-assigning the result of `_a++` to `_a`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your program is trying to find frequencies of different alphabets in a string, and you are counting the non letters in special index 26. In that case your code to initialize the count is wrong. It is getting pre-initialized with some values in following for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < xArray.length; i++) {
        xArray[i] = _a;
        _a = _a++;
    }
```

I think the method can be simply something like:

```
s = s.toLowerCase();
int histogram[] = new int[27];

for (char c: s.toCharArray()) {
    int index = c - 'a';

    if (index < 0 || index > 25) {
        index = 26;
    }

    histogram[index]++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int[] countAll(String s) {
    int[] count = new int[26];

    for (char c : s.toLowerCase().toCharArray()) {
        if ('a' <= c && c <= 'z') {
            count[c - 'a']++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

First.. your arrays where to big.

Second.. why do you need two arrays at all?

Third.. your code didn't seemt to work.. the word "hello" returned an array with the number 97 (26 times) and the number 102.

Edit: Made it shorter.